# create custom object from enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I am trying to map an enum to create an object from the HealthCheckRating enum. for that, I am using the Object.keys method on this enum but somehow I am getting all the keys and values back in the array.

```
    enum HealthCheckRating {
      "Healthy" = 0,
      "LowRisk" = 1,
      "HighRisk" = 2,
      "CriticalRisk" = 3,
    }
     interface healthcheckOption {
    value: HealthCheckRating;
    label: string;
  }

  const healthCheckRatingOptions: healthcheckOption[] = Object.keys(
    HealthCheckRating
  ).map((key) => {
    return {
      value: HealthCheckRating[key as keyof typeof HealthCheckRating],
      label: key,
    };
  });
```

result I am getting is that

```
     [
  { value: "Healthy", label: "0" },
  { value: "LowRisk", label: "1" },
  { value: "HighRisk", label: "2" },
  { value: "CriticalRisk", label: "3" },
  { value: 0, label: "Healthy" },
  { value: 1, label: "LowRisk" },
  { value: 2, label: "HighRisk" },
  { value: 3, label: "CriticalRisk" },
];
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings